Firebase emulator still using real firebase account
Update: It works on Android! So my config probably isn't wrong. It could be an iOS issue.
I'm trying to use the firebase emulator so it doesn't send out emails to my fake test email addresses (which might be real).
When I try to sign a new user up in my dev environment that uses the firebase emulator it is saying the email address is already taken, which it is in my real firebase project but I have no accounts in my emulator, so it should allow the registration.
I used the firebase cli.
It gave me these files:
.firebaserc:
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "vepo-dev",
    "development": "vepo-dev-e5b8a"
  },
  "targets": {},
  "etags": {},
  "dataconnectEmulatorConfig": {}
}

firebase.json (I used host port 5003 temporarily as 5000 was taken):
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099,
      "persist": true
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5003
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}

This is my firebase initialisation in main_development.json:
  // Firebase
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: Env.instance!.firebaseAppName,
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator('localhost', 9099);

So the DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform being used in the block of code above is still a real firebase project, and that is the one that is being used for firebase auth instead of being emulated. So why isn't it using the emulator version that has no accounts and letting me sign up the new user?

Please edit the question to show all relevant code (a complete minimal reproducible example) and the actual error message it generates.  We should be able to take what you have and use it to duplicate the same result.

@DougStevenson There is no error message. Do you want a full flutter app?

How did you observe "it is saying the email address is already taken"?  We need to be able to duplicate that observation with some minimal code that yields the result. Otherwise, how do we know what is actually happening?  If you are certain that your code is not the issue, then Stack Overflow is not the right place to post.  File an issue on firebase-tools instead.  But you will probably still be asked for relevant code there.

@DougStevenson That email address already taken error is coming from firebase auth, it is the exact same one that is returned from the real firebase app when the email is taken, because it is using the real firebase app, not the emulator. What do we do about the firebase console project for a minimal reproducable example app? Create a sample one and make it public if possible?

Certainly you could make an app that does nothing but call the Firebase API to sign in the user, put all the code in a single file, and copy the contents of the file into your post.
